# Why would a rock thrown upwards, a rock thrown sideways and a rock thrown downwards have the same final speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, projectile

This is the full question:

A girl throws a stone from a bridge. Consider the following ways she might throw the stone. The speed of the stone as it leaves her hand is the same in each case. Case A: Thrown straight up. Case B: Thrown straight down. Case C: Thrown out at an angle of 45° above horizontal. Case D: Thrown straight out horizontally. In which case will the speed of the stone be greatest when it hits the water below? Case A Case B Case C Case D The speed will be the same in all cases.

It says that in all 4 cases, the rock arrives at the water below with the same speed. I can't wrap my mind around this idea.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy

Comment: Calculate each of the four cases and see for yourself.  They are all simple trajectory cases.  In doing so, you will probably see why it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conservation of energy. She starts off with the same kinetic energy $\mathrm{KE}_i$, and the work done by gravity is the same in each case, $W_\text{gravity}=mgh$, since each rock falls from the same height.

Thus in each case, the same amount of gravitational potential energy is converted to kinetic energy, so the final kinetic energy is $\mathrm{KE}_f=\mathrm{KE}_i+mgh$.

If she throws it straight up, the rock will go up, then fall to her level. When the rock is at the girl's level, it will have the same speed as it was launched, except now the rock is falling down. So it's equivalent to her throwing the rock directly down. Whether she throws it sideways or downwards, the change in potential energy will always be $-mgh$, which means that in each case, kinetic energy will increase by $mgh$.